# python How to run a function using data from csv file

Tags: python, function, loops, csv

I have a code that does a task on pinterest and it works manually, a number has to be filled in the "pin_id=" area, and when I run, repinning will be done, however, I want to :

1. fill the data in "pin_id" area from a one-column csv file.
2. have some delay between each task ( 5-10 sec).
3. be able to limit the number of rows run on each run,
   e.g. 50, CSV file could have hundreds of data, I don't want to run all data at one go.

[edited] code edited, the latest I tried,
Here is the code:

```
 import json
 import random
 import time
 import os
 from csv import reader
 import csv
 import pandas as pd
 from py3pin.Pinterest import Pinterest

 pinterest = Pinterest(email='xxxx',
                  password='xxxx',
                  username='xxxx',
                  cred_root='cred_root')
  def repin(pin_id='', board_id=myboard Id, section_id=None):
  return pinterest.repin(board_id=board_id, pin_id=pin_id, 
  section_id=section_id)

  with open('pin-test.csv','r') as csvfile:  # use with to auto-close file
  for row in csvfile.readlines():  # pin_id
   repin(row)  # board_id and section can use defaults
   time.sleep(random.randint(1,3)) # wait 1-3 seconds
```

so far no function for limiting the number of rows to be run,

anyhow, the edited script does not work either,

I get these when run:

```
C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master>z-repin-test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master\z-repin-test.py", 
line 40, in <module>
repin(row)  # board_id and section can use defaults

File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master\z-repin-test.py", 
line 35, in repin
return pinterest.repin(board_id=board_id, pin_id=pin_id, 
section_id=section_id)

File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest- 
master\py3pin\Pinterest.py", line 433, in repin
return self.post(url=REPIN_RESOURCE_CREATE, data=data)

File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest- 
master\py3pin\Pinterest.py", 
line 111, in post
return self.request('POST', url=url, data=data, files=files, 
extra_headers=headers)

File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest- 
master\py3pin\Pinterest.py", line 103, in request
response.raise_for_status()

File "C:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in 
raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: 
https://www.pinterest.com/resource/RepinResource/create/
```

appreciate your help with this.

Comment: I'm not following. Perhaps sample data and expected result would clarify. I'll check in tonight.

Comment: thanks for the reply, 
I put pin number in front of "pin_id=" and board number in front of "board_id=", when run, it will repin to my board, but I want to fill the pin_id= with a number from CSV file,( one row), 
the board number is constant and I don't need to change it, so the CSV file has only one column, each row one number

106327241191390329,
10766486599666429,
10836855341311643,
read CSV file code, is just an example I found online and I tried to make it work with the code I have.

Comment: How do you get http errors reading a csv file? :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems straight forward. Just call the function while iterating the data file.

```
import random, time

def repin(pin_id='Id number from csv file', board_id=12345, section_id=None):
   return pinterest.repin(board_id=board_id, pin_id=pin_id, section_id=section_id)
   

with open('pin-test.csv','r') as csvfile:  # use with to auto-close file
   for row in csvfile.readlines():  # pin_id
       repin(row)  # board_id and section can use defaults
       time.sleep(random.randint(1,3)) # wait 1-3 seconds
```

Comment: thank for the reply, it trows couple of errors, I think the "pin_id=" area has to have some value in it,  I left it empty, but it trows error, also if it repins, it does repin all the content at once, I don't want to do it at once, I want to repin them one at the time with some random delay in between.

Comment: Thanks for the edited codes, this is based on Github project (github.com/bstoilov/py3-pinterest)
I get these errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master\z-repin-test.py", line 39, in <module>
    repin(row)  # board_id and section can use defaults

  File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master\z-repin-test.py", line 34, in repin
    return pinterest.repin(board_id=board_id, pin_id=pin_id, section_id=section_id)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master\py3pin\Pinterest.py", line 433, in repin

    return self.post(url=REPIN_RESOURCE_CREATE, data=data)
  File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master\py3pin\Pinterest.py", line 111, in post

    return self.request('POST', url=url, data=data, files=files, extra_headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Dav111\Desktop\Python\py3-pinterest-master\py3pin\Pinterest.py", line 103, in request

    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status

Comment: Update your post with your latest code (or snippet) and add the full error stack trace.

Comment: I updated the script with your script, and still not work, I tried to make it all inside one function, but I could not figure it out how,

Comment: I am not sure how this should work, because when "repin(row)" runs, how the data from row can be inserted inside the function?, isn't it outside of the function?

Comment: if I run "print(row)" it prints one row at a time every few sec. but it does not work running "repin(row)"